# Laravel Query Builder: order by appends field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

My model looks like:

```
protected $appends = array('status');
public function getStatusAttribute()
{
    if ($this->someattribute == 1) {
        $status = 'Active';
    } elseif ($this->someattribute == 2) {
        $status = 'Canceled';
    ...
    } else {
        $status = 'Some antoher status';
    }
    return $status;  
}
```

And I want to order a collection of this models by this `status` attribute, is it possible?

`Model::where(...)->orderBy(???)`

p.s. I need exactly `orderBy`, not `sortBy` solution.

Comment: Can you just `->orderBy("someattribute")`? If not, there's `->orderByRaw()` where you can expand the ordering with `CASE IF ...` etc etc. Besides that, by the time you have the `status` attribute, it's no longer a query builder instance, but a `Collection`, which would use `sortBy` (which you've said is no good)

Comment: no.. append attribute generate after the query.. you need to do collection sort after query

Comment: Why does it have to be an `orderBy()` solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make Eloquent do this because it only creates a SQL query. It does not have the ability to translate the PHP logic in your code into a SQL query.

A work around is to loop over the results afterwards and manually check the appends fields. Collections may be useful here.

Answer (score -1):

Either you can use

```
Model::where(...)->orderBy('someattribute')->get();
```

in this case you will only get integer value in place of `someattribute`, or you can use `DB` query s follows

```
DB::select(DB::raw('(CASE WHEN someattribute = 1 THEN "Active" CASE WHEN someattribute = 1 THEN "Canceled" ELSE "Some antoher status" END) AS status'))
->orderBy('someattribute', 'desc');
```